# Angular 7 linking with iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

I'm trying to bind a link (project.projectUrl) inside an iframe but cannot seem to get it to work. I'm trying to bind the projectUrl from my JSON file to the iframe src so I can dynamically display iframes from within a modal if that is possible. Please see my code in the comment below.

Answer (score 18):

You need to **sanitize** the src. https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl.

One of the ways to do it, in your component constructor:

```
constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer, ....)
```

and then

```
<iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(project.projectUrl)" height="600" width="1000"></iframe>
```

Comment: I figured it out! I created a pipe to handle the transforming of the project url and pass it into the iframe tag. In the case where the url is unable to display, I would like to just display a screenshot of the project. I'll try to work on this next. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: this isn't sanitizing though is it? It's actually saying "don't sanitize but trust anyway"

Answer (score 6):

I fixed my problem by javascript.

In this case you shouldn't use `[]` or `{{}}`.

get element into template by viewChild or something else and set attribute into it.

Here is the code example.

HTML TEMPLATE

```
<iframe #iframe height="600" width="1000"></iframe>
```

IN YOUR COMPONENT

```
export class Component implements AfterViewInit {

   @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.iframe.nativeElement.setAttribute('src', project.projectUrl);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the angular to html injector wrong I believe

```
<iframe [src]="project.projectUrl" height="600" width="1000"></iframe>
```

or

```
<iframe src="{{project.projectUrl}}" height="600" width="1000"></iframe>
```

If you do both you are basically calling this in typescript
`{{project.projectUrl}}` instead of just `project.projectUrl`
I would recommend you using `[src]` as thats what is suggesting in the docs and is easier to read.

Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: Also wouldn't it be better to call your project url `project.imageURL` as you already know that the project object data attributes come from the project.

Comment: I'm trying to bind the project url from my JSON file to the iframe src so I can dynamically display iframes from within a modal if that is possible. Using this code iframe is displaying empty. <iframe [src]="project.projectUrl" height="600" width="1000"></iframe>